# Errata for Rogers' Computability book

Tags: reference-request, computability

I would like to get the errata for the *Theory of recursive functions and effective computability* by Hartley Rogers, 1987 edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there does not seem to be any Errata that somebody would know of, I created a public repository on [Github](https://github.com/dt1510/errata/blob/master/computability/errata_rogers_theory_of_recursive_functions_and_effective_computability.txt) where anybody can add errors or corrections that one spots. Hopefully, as the time goes by, it will become useful to the mathematical community.

Aside, if you do not know Git, it is to my knowledge the best tool for managing the collaborative work, including mathematical research.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen version control software used for anything aside from code before...

Comment: For example the Homotopy type theory book HoTT was written using GitHub.